# cross browser live video streaming

Tags: html, cross-browser, live-streaming

I trying to find an optimal way to make live streaming web client (html5 in ideal and without any plugins) for the video server, which at the moment supports rtsp/rtp h264 streaming and server push of jpeg.

After some investigating, I realised that the server should be modified. Now browsers don't support rtp but h264 is enable from the box. Server push is also not attractive because only safari and `firefox` support it, `chrome` doesn't.

Adding hls and smooth streaming to the server will not solve the problem due to known problems with hls on android.The only real `cross browser` working solution that I've seen is a js script at the client which is requesting jpeg by the timer. Looks a little bit awkward... Any suggestions?